# SQL: Using Not Exists with Nested Query

Tags: sql, exists, sql-except

I'm having trouble understanding how this query works. It is supposed to return the name of customers who have ordered ALL items.

`R` refers to the table of item orders made by customers which contains the customer id (`cid`) and item id (`iid`).
`I` refers to the table of items that can be ordered which contains the item id.
`C` is the customer table with customer id.

```
SELECT cname
FROM Customer C
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(  (SELECT I.iid
       FROM Item I)
    EXCEPT
   (SELECT R.iid
      FROM Order R
      WHERE R.cid=C.cid))
```

The bottom nested query with `SELECT R.iid` gets all the items ordered by any customer.

Then the nested query above the `EXCEPT` with `SELECT I.iid` finds all the items which have not been ordered before by subtracting the result of the query below it.

If it is nested, what statement does `NOT EXISTS` evaluate? Is it `R.cid = C.cid` because of `FROM Customer C`? How does it get to the end result?

Comment: *It is suppose to return the name of customers who have ordered ALL items.* Yes

Comment: The double NOT EXISTS trick will work here.

Comment: You should have asked the question without saying what it's supposed to be doing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT I.iid FROM Item I` means "IDs of all items".

`SELECT R.iid FROM Order R WHERE R.cid=C.cid` means "IDs of all items that customer `C` has ever ordered" (where `C` is determined by the containing query).

In general, `query1 EXCEPT query2` means "all rows that are returned by `query1` and are *not* returned by `query2`". In your specific case, `(SELECT I.iid FROM Item I) EXCEPT (SELECT R.iid FROM Order R WHERE R.cid=C.cid)` means "IDs of all items that customer `C` has *never* ordered".

Inside a `NOT EXISTS (subquery)` expression, all that really matters is whether `subquery` returns any rows (in which case it "exists") or not. So `(SELECT I.iid FROM Item I) EXCEPT (SELECT R.iid FROM Order R WHERE R.cid=C.cid)` exists if there are is any item that customer `C` has *never* ordered — and it *doesn't* exist if there *isn't* any such item.

So the query as a whole finds the name of customers who have ordered every single item.

Answer (score 2):

Break it down.  Starting backwards / with the innermost query:

This returns a list of the Item ID's ordered by the customer.  (I'm assuming iid stands for Item ID, and is an fk in R)

```
SELECT R.iid FROM Order R WHERE R.cid=C.cid
```

This returns a list of item ID's (generally), *except* for those already ordered by the customer

```
SELECT I.iid FROM Item I EXCEPT...
```

Finally, This returns a list of customers who have NOT, NOT ordered one of the items in the list.

```
SELECT cname FROM Customer C Where NOT EXISTS...
```

So basically, you're looking for customers who have ordered at least one of everything.